# How to process whole xml and then return fragments

Tags: spring-batch, etl

I have xml like following for etl processing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OMeS  version="2.3"   adapId="nokrww"  xmlns="pm/cnf_rnc_nsn.7.0.xsd">
  <PMSetup  startTime="2018-10-23T11:00:00.000+05:00:00" interval="15">
    <PMMOResult>
      <MO dimension="network_element">
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/RNC-3/WBTS-500/WCEL-1]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO dimension="MCCMNC">
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/MCC-4/MNC-5]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <PMTarget  measurementType="L3Iub">
        <M1005C0>424</M1005C0>
        <M1005C1>858</M1005C1>
    </PMMOResult>
    <PMMOResult>
      <MO dimension="network_element">
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/RNC-3/WBTS-501/WCEL-2]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO dimension="MCCMNC">
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/MCC-5/MNC-6]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <PMTarget  measurementType="L3Iub">
        <M1005C0>201</M1005C0>
        <M1005C1>300</M1005C1>
    </PMMOResult>
</PMSetup>
</OMeS>
```

If I use **PMMOResult** for fragmentRootElementName I can't access startTime attribute.

If i use **OMes** as fragmentRootElementName i have only one item to write

How can I override StaxEventItemReader to read whole document using OMeS as fragmentRootElementName and then access all nested elements under PMMOResult tags, do some changes and return as List?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The `StaxEventItemReader` can read only one type at a time (from the base contract of an item reader: `ItemReader<T>`). Setting the `fragmentRootElementName` to `PMSetup` to get the `startTime` attribute is possible, but you would end up with one huge `PMSetup` element item in memory with all `PMMOResult` child elements, which is not what you would want.

So I would recommend to proceed in two step:

- step 1: use a tasklet to get any meta-data needed from the "header" elements (and pass it to step 2 through the step execution context if needed)
- step 2: use a chunk-oriented tasklet to process `PMMOResult` elements in chunks by setting the `fragmentRootElementName` to `PMMOResult` in the `StaxEventItemReader`

Hope this helps.

Comment: File size is limited by several megabytes. I think that memory is not a concern. Could you please clarify how can I process file with fragmentRootElementName equal PMSetup

Comment: Well the goal is to get the `startTime` attribute from the parent `PMSetup` then read all **child** elements `PMMOResult` in chunks right? That is *not* possible. What I meant is that nothing prevents you from setting the `fragmentRootElementName` to the parent `PMSetup` to get the start time, but this yields to reading only one item and writing only one item as you said. If memory is not a concern for you, then you can load the whole `PMSetup` object in memory (and get the start time), then use a `ListItemReader` or `IteratorItemReader` and pass child elements `PMSetup.getPMMOResults` to it.