# How to process XML and count based on nested elements in Spring Batch instead of counting based on Parent

Tags: jaxb, spring-batch

I am parsing an xml file using Spring Batch and StaxEventItemReader that contains the below structure.
I am setting FragmentRootElementName as entity, so I get the read count based on top level entity at the after step. But I would like to get the count based on account level.
If I set FragmentRootElementName as account I could get the number of accounts exist in a file but I could not read other elements which are required for processing each account.
I have seen other threads like this [How to process whole xml and then return fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039398/how-to-process-whole-xml-and-then-return-fragments) but could not find working solution.
Could someone shed some ideas how to parse this XML with all elements and get the read count based on nested elements at account level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document>
    <entity>
        <shortname>Test</shortname>
        <city>City-1</id_city>
        <address>Test Address1</address>
        <account>
            <type>Savings</type>
            <iban>IBAN123456</iban>
            <bic>BIC123</bic>
            <bban>123456</bban>
            <curr>USD</curr>
        </account>
        <account>
            <type>Savings</type>
            <iban>IBAN567812</iban>
            <bic>BIC567</bic>
            <bban>56784</bban>
            <curr>USD</curr>
        </account>
        <nal>
            <nal1>Test-1</nal1>
            <nal2>Test-2</nal2>
            <nal3>Test-3</nal3>
        </nal>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <shortname>Test-2</shortname>
        <city>City-2</id_city>
        <address>Test Address2</address>
        <account>
            <type>Savings</type>
            <iban>IBAN123456</iban>
            <bic>BIC123</bic>
            <bban>123456</bban>
            <curr>USD</curr>
        </account>
        <nal>
            <nal1>Test-1</nal1>
            <nal2>Test-2</nal2>
            <nal3>Test-3</nal3>
        </nal>
    </entity>
<document>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using the following approach.

```
//Reset the additional count at the Before step
stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put(count, 0);

//Calculate the nested accounts in the processor and write into step execution context    
Integer additionalCount = stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getInt("count");
additionalCount += accounts.size() - 1;
stepExecution.getExecutionContext().putInt("count" additionalCount);

//Calculate the final read count at After step by summing up step execution default 
//read count and additional account count
int readCount = stepExecution.getReadCount() + additionalCount;
```